# MvvmCross plugin with specific windows phone version specifications

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm writing a plugin but I need a specific implementation for each Windows Phone version.

The problem is that the plugin system will try to load the platform plugin assembly based on a convention. In this case, "WindowsPhone".

We may try to override [CreatePluginManager](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone/Platform/MvxPhoneSetup.cs#L69) but then it will affect the rest of the plugins you may need.

I'm thinking of generating two different projects with different names but the same assembly and namespace. This, I think, would solve the problem of loading the specific plugin but I don't really know how to face an eventual publication to Nuget.

Best regards,

Roberto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating assemblies with the same name is a viable way to go - it is something that the Microsoft Pcl teams do quite frequently - it is how the reference assemblies work.

The nuget distribution of these shouldn't be an issue - but would be a "faff" - as the nuget zip file would use different folders for the different files. There might, however, be some work to do at the .targets level if you want a single project to build both wp7 and wp8 configurations (this is similar to the effort needed for x86/x64/arm variants of assemblies in winrt nuget packages).

In fact, the main reason I can think for not using the same name is the very simple reason that it's far too easy to get in a muddle that way.

---

If for this one plugin, you wanted to override the plugin manager during setup, you could provide custom loading functionality based on

- inheriting from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/Plugins/MvxFilePluginManager.cs
- and then overriding `protected virtual string GetPluginAssemblyNameFrom(Type toLoad)` to add a special  based on some property of `toLoad` - eg `if (toLoad.Name.EndsWith("Foo")) toReturn += PlatformPostfix`

If this pattern becomes common - whether for wp or for the other versioned platforms - then we could include something back into the framework - it would be easy enough to try a version-neutral load followed by a version-specific load for every plugin.

---

There are also other ways you could go about this too...

E.g. Another possibility/opportunity is that your plugin core file could try loading multiple platform adaptions itself - eg using code like

```
    public void EnsureLoaded()
    {
        var manager = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxPluginManager>();
        manager.TryEnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded<PluginLoader>();
        manager.TryEnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded<Sub1.PluginLoader>();
        manager.TryEnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded<Sub2.PluginLoader>();
    }
```

This would try loading three child assemblies for that plugin - MyPlugin.WindowsPhone, MyPlugin.Sub1.WindowsPhone and MyPlugin.Sub2.WindowsPhone although you would only package one of these on each platform.